# JavaScript transform array of objects into an object by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'user@mail.com',
    city: 'London',
    type: 'CLIENT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    email: 'stave@mail.com',
    city: 'Rome',
    type: 'USER'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    city: 'Paris',
    type: 'ADMIN'
  }
]
```

I need to transform it into something like this:

```
{
  CLIENT: {
     name: 'John',
     email: 'user@mail.com',
     city: 'London'
  },
  USER: {
     name: 'Steve',
     email: 'stave@mail.com',
     city: 'Rome',
  },
  ADMIN: {
     name: 'Mark',
     email: 'mark@mail.com',
     city: 'Paris',
     type: 'ADMIN'
  }
}
```

What's the best approach?

Thank you

Comment: What if your array has multiple objects with same `type` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#reduce` with a simple object destructuring to get your desired result:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'user@mail.com',
    city: 'London',
    type: 'CLIENT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    email: 'stave@mail.com',
    city: 'Rome',
    type: 'USER'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    city: 'Paris',
    type: 'ADMIN'
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, { type, ...obj }) => {
  acc[type] = obj;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With upcoming *object rest properties* in [ES2018/ES9](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) or with [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/), you could take the `type` property and use the rest properties for a new object for assignment.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'John', email: 'user@mail.com', city: 'London', type: 'CLIENT' }, { name: 'Steve', email: 'stave@mail.com', city: 'Rome', type: 'USER' }, { name: 'Mark', email: 'mark@mail.com', city: 'Paris', type: 'ADMIN' }],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(({ type, ...o }) => ({ [type]: o })));

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr = [{ name: 'John', email: 'user@mail.com', city: 'London', type: 'CLIENT' }, { name: 'Steve', email: 'stave@mail.com', city: 'Rome', type: 'USER' }, { name: 'Mark', email: 'mark@mail.com', city: 'Paris', type: 'ADMIN' }];

console.log(arr.reduce((r,{type,...rest})=>Object.assign(r,{[type]:rest}),{}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```